# PhoneGap 2.1 on Android returns 404 for local AJAX calls using jQuery

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova

I have PhoneGap (v2.1) project where I'm using jQuery (v1.8.2) to load local XML files via AJAX. I use relative paths (xml/myXMLfile.xml) since the XML files are included in the .apk

AJAX call returns a 404 every time.
The same code works using PhoneGap v2.0.

Comment: What device are you testing on? What android version? Did you try others?

Comment: Show some code as I can load local files.

Comment: Did you solve this yet? I have the same, but for html snippets. index.html loads app.htm, but it returns a 404. But only in an exported APK on a device that hasn't been a debugging device on eclipse...

Comment: Fixed! You shouldn't use jQuery to load local stuff, but the old fashioned XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: what is the difference? jquery.ajax is just a wrapper of XMLHTtpRequest